# navigationBarHidden combined with inline display mode causes jump

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar

I have a parent view, in which I don't want any navigation bar, and a child view, where I want an inline navigation bar.

If I navigate to the child view, then back again. The top of the list will have a weird jump effect when scrolling upwards.

I'm sure this is a bug, but does anyone have a workaround? If it helps, I can get access to the underlying UIScrollView/UINavigationController components - but I'm not sure if any of the properties would help.

[image: Screen recording of the bug]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List( 0...50, id: \.self ) { i in
                NavigationLink(destination: HelloView()) {
                    Text("\(i)")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarHidden( true )
        }
    }
}

struct HelloView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .navigationBarTitle("Hello", displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is odd, but this can be alleviated by setting the `navigationBarTitle` property.  In your desired case I would recommend the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List( 0...50, id: \.self ) { i in
                NavigationLink(destination: HelloView()) {
                    Text("\(i)")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline) /// <<--- Insert this line
            .navigationBarHidden( true )
        }
    }
}
```

By setting the title attribute to blank and using the inline display mode, it rids the view of the large title and *actually* hides the view correctly.

Comment: I thought for sure I tried this already, but you're right it does seem to work.
I went one step further and did `.navigationBarTitle("Back", displayMode: .inline)` so the word 'Back' would still appear in the sub view.
It's not pretty but it will have to do